# Mod_rewrite url vice versa redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't understand and can't find the needed clear information about it.

Is it even possible to rewrite with mod_rewrite `localhost/mysite/index.php?a=search` url to `localhost/mysite/search`?

I have tried with wikipedia `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dog`, then it immediately redirects to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog`. I want similar thing.

I've tried this code on my localhost site .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

it worked when I tried to type in browser something like `localhost/mysite/search` but it is only one part of what I want. Please answer, I'm absolutely exhausted.

Comment: IMO, the easiest way to do this is to just check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in php and if it is the url with the query string, redirect back.

Comment: So is it possible only this way? And mod_rewrite just isn't for this part of url change? And mod_rewrite can keep url mysite/search only when typed directly like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional redirect rule for redirecting to pretty URL. Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, now I have a chace to understand something!

Comment: Can you answer more questions please?
Is there a difference to use 302 redirect or 301 redirect?
And what links format will show search engines in the search results? Will they think that it is one page or two?

Comment: `302` is good for testing since browsers cache `301` permanently. Once verified you can make it `301`

Comment: But in this example when is just needed redirect from site.com?url=string to site.com?url=string? It can be changed to 301 without second thought?
And is it really a common practice to do such redirect? Or it's maybe even don't needed (especially with a new site where I can write links with new urls from the begining)? Is it good to do this for old big site where everywhere old links?

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering, but is "yes" the answer for all questions?

Comment: Yes it is `yes` to all the questions.